# How to convert this inhomogeneous parabolic equation to homogeneous parabolic equation, while boundary data is prescribed?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the one phase parabolic equation
\begin{equation}
\Delta u_{1} - D_{t}u_{1}=-1 
\end{equation}
where $u_{1}>0$ in some domain $\Omega^{+}$, and $u_{1}=0$ on the free boundary, assuming that the free boundary is Lipschitz.

Avoiding the interphase energy balance condition for a moment, I just want to convert this heat equation to homogeneous heat equation. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried that let $v=u_{1} - t$, but the boundary condition does not satisfy, because when $u_{1}=0$, then $v \ne 0$.

Comment: something like $u-{1\over 2}x^2$?

Comment: The right hand side is not zero for this one. Also, $u=0$, then $1/2x^2$ may not be zero, where this function goes?